# Query for Multiple row SQL Where clause

Tags: sql, join, row, where-clause, multiple-columns

Need help for one query which is fetching result from multiple rows based on some condition. For e.g. we have table with [Roll no] with [subjects]. Table can have multiple records for the same [Roll No]. My requirement is if the Student opt for only 'English' then result should return 'E', if Maths then 'M' and if both then 'B'.

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a pretty basic aggregation query with conditional logic.

Comment: Add sample table data and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// I think this is what you want.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.rolls
    ( name, subject )
VALUES  ( 'Jones', 'English'),
( 'Smith', 'Math'),
('Adams','English'),
('Adams', 'Math')
GO

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT subquery1.name, 'B' AS code FROM (
SELECT name,COUNT(name) AS cnt
FROM rolls
WHERE subject = 'English' OR subject = 'Math'
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(name) > 1 ) AS subquery1

UNION 

SELECT subquery2.name, SUBSTRING(rolls.subject,1,1) AS code FROM (
SELECT name,COUNT(name) AS cnt
FROM rolls
WHERE subject = 'English' OR subject = 'Math'
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(name) = 1 ) AS subquery2
INNER JOIN dbo.rolls
ON rolls.name = subquery2.name
)

SELECT * FROM CTE
```